# Set Alert when user view DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

Set Alert when user view DIV

I have tried to add Session and etc, but it keeps showing me the alert more than once. 
I need it show me alert only once per reload.
I've done the most parts but it still display me more than once the alert and after I scroll off and back it won't show again (as I needed).
I need something that will prevent show alert box more than once because it's madness pressing OK 5-11 times till it disappears.

[The code in >>>JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Orbitfum/3vtgw75x/3/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#mid').offset().top,
       hH = $('#mid').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
 var yetVisited = sessionStorage['visited'];     
    //console.log((hT-wH) , wS);
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH) && wS < (hT-hH+wH) && !yetVisited){   
     $('#alert').fadeIn(3000);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#alert").fadeOut(3000);
      }, 5000); 
    if (!yetVisited) {
                alert("Mid box alert!");

    }
      sessionStorage['visited'] = "yes";
   }

console.log(sessionStorage);
});
```

thank for help.

**Solution :** 
[JSFiddle Solution by Walk](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lrbe7uc/)

Comment: works for me on chrome, in the fiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle works. Alert is only displayed once during initial reload. Tested in chrome and IE.

Comment: sooo.. it's works? unbelievable... and i'm using firefox ...

Comment: For me it also is displayed multiple times on initial load, I'm also using Firefox. The problem here is that scroll event fires too many times, you can throttle it.

Comment: Something like this should do the trick https://jsfiddle.net/5Lrbe7uc/